# Can I return from an `async` function from within a nested callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I've got a pretty strong grasp of ES6, but I can't wrap my head around this:

How can I return from an `async` function from within a nested callback?

e.g.:

```
async function test () {
    someNonPromiseUsingFunction (data => return data)
}
```

as opposed to nesting everything in a promise:

```
function test () {
    return new Promise (resolve => someNonPromiseUsingFunction (data => resolve (data)))
}
```

I know it's not *necessary*, I just want to consistently use `async` and `await` in my code instead of mixing it with manual promise initializations.

Comment: TL;DR - `async` only works with Promises. If you want to use `async` functions, you will have to make sure that all of the values you want to `await` on are Promises.

Comment: `async` gives you promise-`await`, not magical callbacks. You still need to promisify them as usual.

Comment: In your particular example, you can simplify `data => resolve (data)` to just `return new Promise (resolve => someNonPromiseUsingFunction (resolve))`, or even `new Promise(someNonPromiseUsingFunction)`